# Kendo Scheduler - Event not showing

Tags: javascript, json, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-scheduler

I'm trying to show the events in the Kendo Scheduler but it's not working. I think it's because the JSON date format that is coming from the server is not in the correct format. Any help is appreciated.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Scheduler<TaskViewModel>()
.Name("Scheduler")
.Date(DateTime.Today)
.Views(views =>
{
    views.DayView();
    views.WeekView();
    views.MonthView();
})
.Timezone("Etc/UTC")
.DataSource(d => d
    .Model(m =>
    {
        m.Field(f => f.Title);
        m.Field(f => f.Start);
        m.Field(f => f.End);
        m.Field(f => f.IsAllDay); 
    })
.Read(read => read.Action("GetScheduleEvent", "DataSource"))
)
)
```

JSON response

```
[{"RecurrenceRule":null,
  "RecurrenceException":null,
  "IsAllDay":true,
  "Start":"\/Date(1455775200000)\/",
  "StartTimezone":null,
  "End":"\/Date(1456034400000)\/",
  "EndTimezone":null,
  "Title":"Test Event"
}]
```

Comment: How does your markup look like (i.e. how is this view rendered into html) ?

Comment: I don't see any data. <div id="Scheduler" class="k-widget k-scheduler k-floatwrap" data-role="scheduler" role="grid" aria-multiselectable="true" style="">
<div class="k-floatwrap k-header k-scheduler-toolbar">
<table class="k-scheduler-layout k-scheduler-dayview k-scrollbar-h">
<div class="k-header k-scheduler-footer">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Ram: There is no problem with the date format. Your JSON response is not in the correct format. It should be in this format

```
{"Data":[],"Total":55,"AggregateResults":null,"Errors":null}
```

My Guess is you might have forgotten to call ToDataSourceResult method as shown below

```
public virtual JsonResult Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            return Json(taskService.GetAll().ToDataSourceResult(request));
        }
```

I have created raw JsonData with the help of your JSON response. Below is the code snippet I used for testing and it is working. Hope this helps you!!

```
public ContentResult GetScheduleEvent([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            //string jsonString = "{\"Data\":[{\"RecurrenceRule\":null, \"RecurrenceException\":null,  \"IsAllDay\":false,  \"Start\":\"Sat Feb 20 2016 01:17:07 GMT-0700 (PDT)\",  \"StartTimezone\":null,  \"End\":\"Sat Feb 20 2016 04:17:07 GMT-0700 (PDT)\",  \"EndTimezone\":null,  \"Title\":\"Test Event\"}],\"Total\":1,\"AggregateResults\":null,\"Errors\":null}";
            string jsonString = "{\"Data\":[{\"RecurrenceRule\":null, \"RecurrenceException\":null,  \"IsAllDay\":true,  \"Start\":\"\\/Date(1455775200000)\\/\",  \"StartTimezone\":null,  \"End\":\"\\/Date(1456034400000)\\/\",  \"EndTimezone\":null,  \"Title\":\"Test Event\"}],\"Total\":1,\"AggregateResults\":null,\"Errors\":null}";
            return new ContentResult { Content = jsonString, ContentType = "application/json" };
        }
```